# How to solve npm install error “npm ERR! code 1”?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, three.js, npm-install

> I'm trying to install [this](https://github.com/Anemolo/StickyImageEffect) project, when I write npm install I get this issue:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.1 found at "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.33214.272) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed
```

I have tried reinstalling Node.js, but it didn't help. What should I do?

I have tried reinstalling Node.js, but it didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: try to remove package-lock.json file and the run command 'npm i'

Comment: Did you do what it said to?

Comment: @TatulMkrtchyan  then ?

Comment: You need to install [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) as suggested by the error message.

Comment: @GOTO0 should I install node-gyp in the project root folder ?

Comment: @El3aber I tried to install and got the same error message, then I deleted the 'package-lock.json' and tried again. It worked fine and installed without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error message is saying you need to install Visual Studio first:

"You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
For more information consult the documentation at:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows "

Answer (score 0):

Usually people meet this error probably because they aren't able to get the precompiled binary of the target package.

The reason why many well-maintained packages(C++ add-ons) provide precompiled binaries and we should use them is because **it's almost impossible to build it from source**, lacking of the needed compilation environment

It cannot guarantee that the package maintainer will provide a precompiled binary for every execution environment(determined by Node.js version and OS). You met the problem because there is no matched precompiled binary for your environment or you cannot reach the server the author put the binaries on.

If it's the former case, you can **upgrade your Node.js or the package** to find a matching precompiled binary, so that npm won't build the package from source